# My Android 4.1.2 is not getting updated or shown in the list of Android versions

Tags: android, eclipse, nokia

I have installed **Nokia X services SDK** and the Android tool. I have set up the existing Android eclipse IDE.

I have tested my apk file and corrected the incompatibilities.

Android 4.1.2 is not showing in the list of android versions while looking into the properties of my android app by right click->android->Android versions

and Java Build path

Comment: I think it is the time to Update oth your Android SDk, API as well as your devices/ Smart phone to test and you will get a new simulator or Emulatore too.

Answer (score 1):

> Android 4.1.2 is not showing in the list of android versions while looking into the properties of my android app by right click->android->Android versions

You need to download the "SDK Platform" for Android 4.1.2 in your SDK Manager. Simply installing the Nokia X plugin will not do this, as that is mostly supplying you with X-specific emulator images.

Also note that you do not need to set your build target to 4.1.2 in order to create apps for the Nokia X series.

Comment: Yes    have been to sdk Manager and installed  Android 4.1.2 also.


I have  selected or marked them n sdk mangaer and installed


I can show you the screenshots also.


Thanks for quick reply